# Socket Listener (on Linux)

Tags: linux, sockets, daemon

I'm searching for a way to listen to a specific port on a specific ip and just dump all incoming data.

It has to work on linux, perferrably something that comes as debian package but if i have to compile it thats fine to.

Would be nice if the data gets stored in a mysql database, but just a file would be ok to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions but i had to go another way...

There is a Debian Package called 'ucspi-tcp' which contains 'tcpserver'

tcpserver just listens on a port and pipes everything into a process you specify.
In my case i wrote a little script that stores the data in a mysql Database.

Answer (score 4):

use command

```
 nc -l hostname 10000  > op.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

[netcat](http://nc110.sourceforge.net/), often packaged as `nc`, is a great tool for such tasks.

Comment: Is it possible to tell netcat to accept multiple clients and keep running?
I didnt find anything like this in the manfile but i need to dump all incoming data, not just from one connection...

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but a quick Google brought this page up: http://www.jfranken.de/homepages/johannes/vortraege/netcat_inhalt.en.html#ToC7

Answer (score 0):

You can always use Nmap (more advanced).

It is an utility for network exploration or security auditing...

Link: http://nmap.org/

Answer (score 0):

Another tool you can use is ngrep / very similar to tcpdump but you can tell it to only listen for packets containing a certain string. 
You can specify a port and source and destination IP as well

Answer (score 0):

Yet another tool is tcpdump and its descendants:

```
sudo tshark -w /tmp/out.pcap -s 2000 -i eth0 ip host 198.51.100.99 and tcp port 80
```